# How to configure certain keywords to bring certain URL in Sharepoint Search?

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, keyboard, ranking

We have about 20 sharepoint internal site. so when people type coffee, sugar, it will show this webportal first (portal.foo.com/kitchensupplies) in the search. when people type computer, batteries, etc, then it will bring up this site first in the list (portal.foo.com/electronicsupplies)

does it call ranking keyword with site (or portal in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for is called Best Bets. Here's a TechNet article on how to [add keyword terms with Best Bets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835625).